# .LIC / Licence (AjaxUploader.lic) not copy after publish / build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ajaxuploader

I recently checked that the ajaxuploader license file is not copied to the IIS publishing folder, I tried with the options in the file property of:
Build Action = None / Content
Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always

However for .lic files this seems to be ignored

I've also tried to copy through the Build Events in .WEB properties using Xcopy commands, but I could not solve the problem.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to figure out the problem ...

Let's go there to solve the problem add these lines in webConfig:

```
<remove extension=".lic"/>
<add extension=".lic" type="System.Web.Compilation.ForceCopyBuildProvider"/>
```

They should be in the following structure:

```
<Configuration>
   <System.web>
      <Compilation>
         <BuildProviders>
           <Remove extension=".lic"/>
           <Add extension=".lic"
               Type="System.Web.Compilation.ForceCopyBuildProvider"/>
         </BuildProviders>
      </Compilation>
   </system.web>
</Configuration>
```

By analyzing the publish output I found that the ajaxuploader.lic file can not be interpreted by "aspnet_compiler.exe", it does not understand the .lic and ends up ignoring it, if you try to change the extension .lic to nothing or to .exe , .txt the file will rise, knowing that I analyzed that in the publication when it executes aspnet_compiler.exe doing the trasnferencia:

Of the folder: obj \ Development \ AspnetCompileMerge \ Source
To folder: obj \ Development \ AspnetCompileMerge \ TempBuildDir

In the Source folder the .lic file already exists in the TempBuildDir folder it disappears, the problem itself is that when executing the command aspnet_compiler.exe with source -> target (TempBuildDir) the .lic file is not copied, so the keys are placed in the Webconfig specifically serves to remove the .lic extension before aspnet_compiler.exe is run and then adds the .lic to the file.

Hugs